# Guitar chords custom tag simple parser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parsing, markdown

Im using markdown for storing lyrics with chords and it works great.
    https://codepen.io/rrob/pen/GxYgOP
Using * for tag `<em>` for chords and positionig it with css.

But now I want it in presentation and markdown parsing is complicated there. 
I try to insert tag with **str.replace** but I cant close tag.

```
text text *chord* text text
```

is replaced with:

```
text text <em>chord<em> text text
```

and I of course need:

```
text text <em>chord</em> text text
```

Pls do you know some simple solution for parsing custom tags like this?
Javascript / Jquery.

Comment: Interesting project!

Comment: Yes, right now im using remarkjs with lyrics on tablet shared via chromecast to projector. But its complicated to customize remark and markdown. Im building it from scratch but simplier. Parsing chords is now solved thanks to Rory and next step is some simple jumping between slides. 
This is first version with remark: http://chvaly.robinpecha.cz/DS-ZDAR/Blizsie%20(Tvoja%20laska%20vzala%20mi%20dych).html#1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Regex to achieve what you require. You can capture the `*` characters along with the characters between them and then replace the `*` with `<em>` tags. Something like this:

```js
var input = 'text text *chord* text text *chord* text';
var output = input.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, '<em>$1</em>');

console.log(output);
```

Given your Codepen example, the complete thing would look something like this:

```js
$('.chords').html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, '<em>$1</em>');
});
```

```css
body {
  white-space: pre-line
}

em {
  line-height: 2.3em;
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  top: -1em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chords">
  You *Emi*stood before creation
  Eternity within *A*Your hands
  You *G*spoke all li*D*fe into motion
  My *A*soul now to *Fdur*stand
</div>
<div class="chords">
  My *A*soul now to *Fdur*stand
  You *G*spoke all li*D*fe into motion
  Eternity within *A*Your hands
  You *Emi*stood before creation
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for your quick reply, pls can you help me with code, let it read and replace content of <div>.

Comment: Ooooooo, it works with small code like this, without markdown parser. Really, really, really thank you. This is amazing community.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: One more question please. Replacing content of div specified by ID? To be sure if will be more divs added in future with different content?

Comment: If you're going to have multiple divs I'd suggest using the same `class` on them all. Then the above code will work for all of them without any need for changes. I've updated the answer again to show you it working on multiple instances

Comment: Perfect, now I know how to do it, just simple replacing div .class #id in code. Again, big thanks!
Is here some way to give you some reputation?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the following function. It iterates each character in the string and replaces the the '*' with `<em>` or `</em>` where needed.

```
/**
 * parse function parse the input raw string and replaces the
 * the star(*) with <em> and </em> where needed.
 * @returns Returns the replaced string.
 */
function parse(str) {
    var ret = ""; // initialize the string.

    for (var x = 0; x < str.length; ++x) {
        if (str[x] == '*') { // The opening.
            ret += "<em>";
            ++x;

            for(; x < str.length; ++x) {
                if (str[x] == '*') { // and the ending is here.
                    ret += "</em>";
                    break;
                } else {
                    ret += str[x];
                }
            }
        } else {
            ret += str[x];
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

console.log(parse("Hello *JS*")); // outputs 'Hello <em>JS</em>

var element = document.querySelector('.chords');
element.innerHTML = parse(element.innerText);
```

Comment: It means, it can work without jquery? Pls can you tell this script to modify object with specified css class? .D

Comment: @rrob I have just did the job for replacing the text.

Comment: @rrob And for appending to any html tag you have to use `jQuery` by using `.append` function

Comment: @rrob Sorry, I'm less familiar with codepen but this worked for me in the chrome. I have added two lines at the end of the code, that will do the stuffs for replacing the html text.